# Running Time recursive algorithm

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I would like to understand if I find myself in a similar situation how to come up with the T (n). Suppose we have an algorithm of the following type:

```
EXAMPLE(P, R):   //
    for i=1 to n:   //where n is the n-th element of the set P
       P_subset = {}   //initially empty subset of P
       for j=i+1 to n:
           if condition 1:
              replace P[i] with something else 
           if condition 2:
              add Pij to P_subset  //Pij is the intersection of the element P[i] and P[j]  
       if P_subset is not empty
           EXAMPLE(P_subset, R)
       if P[i] it is not contained in R
           add P[i] to R  //
```

the intersection could be, assuming that P is an array consisting of elements of type struct of the following type

```
{key, array of value} -> {A, 1234},
```

given by the elements in common to the array of values ​​of the struct:

```
{A, 1234} and {B, 2456} have in common 24.
```

How can the recurrence equation of such an algorithm be found and solved?

Comment: There's no way to know without knowing 'condition 1', 'condition 2' and the 'something else', and also probably a lot more info about P. You can easily make the runtime quadratic in n or infinite or anything in between. What have you tried so far, and what issues did you encounter?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, actually this type of algorithms I encounter them in data mining suit many times, they are somewhat similar. A practical example can be found at the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71496284/charm-recursive-algorithm-complexity-in-loop; solved one, the others can also be solved in the same way.